# AWS K8S: how to authenticate with "access key" in postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

we have to use the K8S API with postman and authenticate with "*access key*"

On AWS K8S we configured the access key:
[image]

In Postman we tested the Authorization Type "*AWS Signature*" and AccessKey / SecurityKey from AWS (clear text and base64-coded) but always get a  *403 forbidden* and the user is not identified (see response: User: system:anonymous)
[image]

Did anyone make a successful connection from postman to AWS K8S with authentication type "*access key*"?

Comment: Did you add IAM user to aws-auth ConfigMap in EKS?

Comment: @VasiliiAngapov yes